Implementing a Structural Equation Model with lasso regression
I have the following structural equation model (SEM) structure in mind:

In reality there are more than 3,2, resp. 3 variables, so I want to use lasso regression for the arrows. Is it possible to implement this in python? I saw some packages in R (e.g. lavaan, regsem), but it seems like a basic task that should also be possible in python. I'm not very proficient in R, so I would prefer a python implementation.
Thanks in advance!
I tried to use semopy, but it does not seem to be maintained anymore.
